# move pg_catalog tables to another no-default tablespace

Tags: postgresql

We are getting below error while moving system_catalog table to non-default tablepsaces(means in those tablespace which are not assigned as default tablespace for  `test` database

For example:

```
 test=# select schemaname,tablename,tablespace,tableowner from pg_tables where schemaname='pg_catalog' and tablename='pg_attribute';
 schemaname |  tablename   | tablespace | tableowner
------------+--------------+------------+------------
 pg_catalog | pg_attribute |   tbs1     | pginst13
(1 row)

 

test=# ALTER TABLE pg_catalog.pg_attribute set tablespace pg_default;
ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_attribute" is a system catalog
```

I am not able to find any information in doc that shows we can't do above.

Thank you for help.

Comment: This sounds like a really strange thing to do. What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the catalog tables of a database to another tablespace, move the database to that tablespace:

```
\c postgres

ALTER DATABASE test SET TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

If you want to move an individual catalog table, you have to change [`allow_system_table_mods`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-developer.html#GUC-ALLOW-SYSTEM-TABLE-MODS) to `on`. Then you should be able to use `ALTER TABLE` on a catalog.

However, I don't think that is a good idea. First, I see no benefit. Second, the change will be lost when you upgrade PostgreSQL, Finally, the documentation for `allow_system_table_mods` warns you in no uncertain terms:

> Ill-advised use of this setting can cause irretrievable data loss or seriously corrupt the database system.

Comment: Hello Laurenz, Thanks for your quick ans. we want to move particular catalog tables not database to another tablespace.

Comment: Either all catalogs or none of them.

Comment: Thanks for you ans. if you don't mind may I know official doc link.. actually i want to show to end users they want from PG officials.

Comment: There actually is a ways that should make it possible, although I don't recommend it. See the updated answer.