# System catalog move - PostgreSQL v. 12.4

Tags: postgresql

We have requirement from end user they want to move system catalog and we have moved system catalog tables as per great Ans from Laurenz Albe
: [move pg_catalog tables to another no-default tablespace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/294999/move-pg-catalog-tables-to-another-no-default-tablespace?noredirect=1#comment576534_294999)

As per Ans., we have moved but still there are some almost 4 system catalog tables which are not able to move as shown in below.

```
testdb=# show allow_system_table_mods ;
 allow_system_table_mods
-------------------------
 on
(1 row)

testdb=# ALTER TABLE pg_catalog.pg_type set tablespace pg_default;
ERROR:  cannot move system relation "pg_type"
testdb=# ALTER TABLE pg_catalog.pg_proc set tablespace pg_default;
ERROR:  cannot move system relation "pg_proc"
testdb=# ALTER TABLE pg_catalog.pg_class set tablespace pg_default;
ERROR:  cannot move system relation "pg_class"
testdb=# ALTER TABLE pg_catalog.pg_attribute set tablespace pg_default;
ERROR:  cannot move system relation "pg_attribute"
testdb=#
```

Can you please let me know what could be reason? It's not recommended but end user want this.

Thanks..

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is the underlying problem you are trying solve with that dirty hack?

Comment: The application team wants their application tables and system catalog tables should be in a separate tablespace. Thanks.

Comment: Then move the application tables to a non-default tablespace - don't mess around with the system tables. But in general tablespaces are really rarely need in Postgres to bein with - what's the problem you are trying to solve with moving the tables to a different tablespace?

Comment: As we know, some file systems impose mount point size limits. so we move tables to another mount point. DB size is more than 2 TB